# Where can I get a Free Material design based theme

Tags: design-patterns, themes

We are starting a project, where we want to download free material design theme based framework (With MIT License) to reduced development effort and time. 
similar to angular material and bootstrap material.

For angular my development team is hesitant to convert the code to Angular 2, which according to them would be a total rewrite, however they can use bootstrap.

Like "mdbootstrap" which has a paid pro version, I wanted to check if anyone knows similar good frameworks which is not paid and also complete with all components and interaction patterns as per material design

I know, many templates are available free in the internet, but I am not looking for a template.

Comment: Have you checked Material Design resources? https://material.io/guidelines/resources/layout-templates.html

Comment: I know, templates are available in that url, but i am looking for a ready made free full version framework, which I can recommend the developers to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for Wordpress or other CMS themes? If so, you can find some here: http://materialdesignthemes.com/themes/

If you're looking for a good framework, you can download one here: https://mdbootstrap.com/

Comment: I am looking for a framework, thus i have looked at mdbootstrap....it is good but since the pro version is a paid one. I am looking for a pro version with MIT license.

Comment: You can try this one here: http://ionicmaterial.com/

Answer (score 0):

**http://www.material-ui.com/#/**

If you are looking for full templates check sites like envato, there are many, one google search should be enough.

Comment: I know, templates are available, but i am looking for a ready made free full version framework, which I can recommend the developers to follow like mdbootstrap whose pro version is paid.